# RuntimeError: view size is not compatible with input tensor's size and stride (at least one dimension spans across two contiguous subspaces)

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch

I am using Pytorch. I got this RuntimeError while evaluating a model. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: This link can be helpful https://github.com/cezannec/capsule_net_pytorch/issues/4

Answer (score 18):

**SOLUTION:** Just replace the **view()** function with **reshape()** function as suggested in the error and it works.

I guess this has to do with how the tensor is stored in memory.

Answer (score 10):

**SOLUTION2**: change the `.view(...)` to `.contiguous().view(...)`.

Actually, 'reshape()' does a similar job as contiguous() under the hood, if it needs.